# Google Adsense responsive add not displayed correctly

Tags: html, css, adsense

I have Google Adsense responsive ads on my web site. They are supposed to be displayed inside their parent container, but very often they overflow it.

A simple example page, a DIV with an add inside it: http://adriatic.aventin.hr/_test.php

Usualy when the browser (BODY element) is > 500px wide, ad display is correct, but when it's resized to < 400px the display will often be incorrect (vertical overflow). I could of course hide the overflow, but the add would be partially cut off, so it's not an option.

I have tried various code changes, but without success. Any ideas?

Sample page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<div style="width: 320px; height: 70px; border: 3px solid red">

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-5645119364072707"
     data-ad-slot="9521328853"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved - the trick is not to set the height of the div.

Comment: I actually have the exact same problem. But i don't have any heights set to any parent div, or the element it self.

Site:
http://portugal.dk.linux134.unoeuro-server.com/

Example:
https://gyazo.com/1d92aab5ea46b7b5fdb09dbd442573dd